# Does pool.map() from multiprocessing lock process to CPU core automatically?

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary, multiprocessing

I've submitted several questions over last few days trying to understand how to use the `multiprocessing` python library properly.

Current method I'm using is to split a task over a number of processes that is equal to the number of available CPU cores on the machine, as follows:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from contextlib import closing

def myFunction(row):
    # row function

with closing(Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())) as pool:
    pool.map(myFunction, rowList)
```

However, when the map part is reached in the program it seems to actually slow down, not speed up. One of my functions for example moves through only 60 records (the first function) and it prints a result at the end of each record. The record printing seems to slow down to an eventual stop and do not much! I am wondering if the program is loading the next function into memory async or whether there's something wrong with my methodology.

So I am wondering - are the child processes automatically 'LOCKED' to each CPU core with the `pool.map()` or do I need to do something extra?

EDIT:

So the program does not actually stop, it just begins to print the values very slowly.

here is an example of `myFunction` in very simplified terms (row is from a list object):

```
def myFunction(row):
    d = string
    j=0
    for item in object:
        d+= row[j]
        j=j+1
    d += row[x] + string
    d += row[y] + string
    print row[z]
    return
```

As I said, the above function is for a very small list, however the function proceeding it deals with a much much larger list.

Comment: Can you share the actual contents of `myFunction`? Or at least enough of it for us to reproduce the behavior you're seeing? If you just use the built-in `map` instead of `pool.map`, does it show a similar slowdown?

Comment: The direct answer to your question is that `multiprocessing.Pool` just creates a bunch of processes for you, and provides IPC and management for sending data to and from those processes. The way the CPU is allocated to those processes is completely controlled by the underlying Operating System.

Comment: "slow down" - compared to what?  And yes, you'll need to provide us with minimal code to reproduce.  There are myriad pitfalls with multiprocessing, some obvious and some less so - we can't divine which one you may be falling into.

Comment: The processes run at the whim of the Operating System scheduler, which can move them around to different CPUs as it chooses. Large datasets and all processes competing for a limited single resource can slow mp down. As a first step, have all child processes print their input and output data sizes, and implement a timer to see how much time each one uses. Maybe your return values are large and its time consuming to get them back into the parent.

Comment: All, please see updated Question above ^ @tdelaney how can i access the child process (ie. which part of the code?)

Comment: @sidewaiise Are you sure that using `multiprocessing` to call `myFunction(some_obj)` makes running `myFunction` slower than calling `myFunction(some_obj)` directly?

Comment: @dano I don't have timer evidence... however it is visibly slower.

Comment: The only possibility I can think of is that running a bunch of `myFunction` instances in parallel is putting memory strain on the system, and causing swapping, which would slow things down. Other than that, there's no reason for the behavior you're seeing that I can think of.

Comment: How big is each `row`? How many elements and what's the total length of the all the strings in each `row`?

Comment: @dano the system has 32Gb memory, running 2x Quad-core CPUs... which is why this delay is puzzling. FYI - I've started gettign some errors with the functions that execute immediately after... so am debugging those and will see if there's any improvement.

Comment: Actually I don't think my previous question matters. Is `myFunction` doing anything more substantial than what you've indicated? Is it doing anything other than pasting together strings from `row`?

Comment: @RossRidge I'm sending the result to a log file on another server.

Comment: Have made it past the long pause - however at each pool.map (I have about 8 of them in series) there is a long pause before any sign of the next one executing. 5-20 minutes... seems proportional to the size of the next list to be processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't appear to be doing enough work in each call to the worker function. All you seem to be doing is pasting together list of strings being passed as argument. However this is pretty much exactly what the multiprocessing module needs to do in the parent process to pass the list of strings to the worker process. It pickles them, writes them to a pipe, which the child process then reads, unpickles and then passes as argument to `myFunction`.

Since in order to pass the argument to the worker process the parent process has to do at least as much work as the worker process needs to do, you gain no benefit from using the multiprocessing module in this case.

Comment: It would seem your last sentence is dead-on correct. I may simply give up on this and call the functions in sequence. It takes about 2-3 hours to get through most of it though using a single-process approach. I was hoping to cut that down to 15-30 min

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help - I think Ross has summed it up nicely - there is obviously a data load/proc ratio where multiprocessing is useful but I don't think my job has a good enough ratio for it to be useful (after all that). Do you think this kind of job would be suitable for Hadoop?

Comment: @sidewaiise Where is `rowList` coming from?

Comment: @dano it's a sublist of a CSV

Comment: @sidewaiise you could have each child process read the csv individually, and just assign each one chunks of the list. That would avoid the high IPC overhead

Comment: @dano Yes that is quite possibly a solution, although I'm not sure what would stop each child process reading the ENTIRE CSV and not just particular ranges.

Comment: @sidewaiise You would have to iterate over the file until you hit the range you wanted, but you wouldn't have to keep the unwanted range in memory.

Comment: @dano i tried an implementation where the memory-stored variable prepopulation tasks were split among the workers. It seemed that once I had done this, the variables were not available to the other functions to be called at a later time.